# How to create numpy array of steps (equivalent to Matlab's stairs) as plotted in matplotlib.pyplot.step(x,y)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Having two numpy arrays:

```
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>> y = np.array([-1,1,-1,1])
```

Is there a function to create equivalent arrays xb,yb, similar to the Matlab function [[xb,yb]=stairs(x,y)](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html)? Where:

```
>>> xb
array([0,0,1,1,2,2,3])
>>> yb
array([-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1])
```

Or perhaps to retrieve the arrays from matplotlib.pyplot.step(x,y)?
[image: below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy recipe is to use `numpy.repeat`

```
xb = numpy.repeat(x, 2)[:-1]
yb = numpy.repeat(y, 2)[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very easy indeed. And switching the behaviour between 'pre' and 'post' is just a matter of switching the indexing between xb and yb.